# If $A$ is real matrix such that $A^m=0$ for some integer $m > 1$, is $t=0$ the only eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering about the following: $m>1$ integer, and $A$ real matrix. $A^m=0$. Is $t=0$ the only eigenvalue of A?

Is it true?

Comment: Yes! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I tried to prove, but found it complex. any suggestions?

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Av = \lambda v$, so $A^2v = \lambda^2 v$ .... $A^m v = \lambda^m v$.

Comment: Seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix)?

Comment: @user16268: Prove the more general implication: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$; this holds for all $n\gt 0$, and also for all negative $n$ if $A$ is invertible. (Careful: The implication is not reversible).

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of an eigenvalue.  $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if there exists a vector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$.  Hence $A^m v=\lambda^m v$.  But what is $A^m v$ if $A^m$ is the all zeros matrix?  What does that tell us about the other side $\lambda^m v$?  Can you solve it from here?